# how to covert UIImage to white in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage

how to convert UIImage to white in iOS, like UITabBar.
In UITabBar, the Image is black, but it display as white color.
Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Gemmell's [MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities) does this.

Comment: coob, thanks for your help. But I think it's complex, and if iOS SDK provide some simple method？

Comment: It doesn't, hence why this was written. The code isn't that complicated, see [this file](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities/blob/master/Classes/UIImage%2BTint.m).